# Forçar indexação do Google em redirecionamento DNS

Tags: google, dns, back-end

**tl;dr:** Redirecionamento via DNS. Usuário é redirecionado para nossa hospedagem. Googlebot ignora e indexa a hospedagem original.

Na nossa hospedagem colocamos os arquivos do site um domínio que está sendo cuidado por outra empresa.

Apesar do site abrir corretamente, ***aparentemente*** foi feito um redirecionamento DNS pra nossa hospedagem, afinal o who.is mostra o DNS "verdadeiro".

Por isso, estamos tendo problemas com indexação no Google porque apesar de termos metatags e robots.txt, nada da NOSSA hospedagem está sendo indexado. O console do Google, acusa erro 5xx (arquivos bloqueados) e exibe os arquivos da hospedagem original sendo indexados não o nosso para onde o usuário e o domínio está apontando.

Algum jeito de forçar que o Googlebot siga esse redirecionamento DNS?

Comment: Problema resolvido. Quem fez o redirecionamento esqueceu a chave TXT. Quem tiver o mesmo problema, verifique todas as chaves que aparecem na zoan de DNS avançada do cPanel.